# Apk file not installing in android says "You may not have proper app for viewing this content"

Tags: samsung, apk

I'm trying to install apk file in Samsung but it says "You may not have proper app for viewing this content". I've checked "allow installation from unknown source" option in security, but no luck. Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Are you sure the file is an APK file?

Comment: Can you link us to this file you're trying to install, so that one of us can inspect it?

Comment: Either it's a broken .apk file or not actually .apk file, or your file manager is dumb for some reason try with some other file manager to locate and install app from .apk. Also do as DMS said upload a file and give us a link to see what it is actually

Comment: It's not that the file is neither APK nor a broken one. I've installed the same in another mobile phone and it worked well. I've downloaded the file from below link. [link]https://www.apk4fun.com/link/3684/a/

Comment: @learner1 What browser did you use? What's the file size, as reported by Samsung's file manager?

Comment: Where did you tap the APK file? It's application-dependent. Some apps just deny access to some file types.

Answer (score 10):

Such Issues generally occur when you try to open the file from within an Application (Messenger, Whatsapp etc.) other than File Manager (any such application with similar privileges) or Play Store.

So, please make sure you are accessing it from File Manager.

> If you are not aware of the source of the APK and if it's not from a trusted source please don't install it directly.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem only in Samsung, but in all mobiles including latest Xiomi not supporting installation from messangers like WhatsApp.

If you want to install apps you can open your file explorer and go to WhatsApp folder -> media folder and then WhatsApp documents. There you can find the apk file
or 
you can search your apk file name 
or
just search .apk and you can find the apk file.

For Xiaomi uses :
Open file manager,
you can find the latest files in the first page, or
in the second page you can find an option 'apks'. In that you can find your apk file from WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

Go to any file managing app , search your .apk file and install from there. I had got the same error when I tried to open the .apk I sent via whatsapp in whatsapp.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue.. But its installing when i open in FileManger App

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not caused by whether apk installer is present or not in your system. As far as I know, WhatsApp (or Android) still doesn't support installing app from inside app other than file manager. The only way is installing it from a file manager app.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error because I was trying to install it from whatsApp and also I forgot to uninstall previous version of same .apk file from Mobile.First check if you have any previous version of apk. If you have it then uninstall it.Then go to File Manager->Internal Storage->WhatsApp->Media->WhatsAppDoc. Here you will find your apk file.Install it from there.Also turn on the option Allow installation from unknown sources from Setting->Security.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to install app showing error.. "unable to read properties for this app"

It is bcoz phone internal installer is unable to read said app properties

Simple install file manager from playstore like astro file manager or ez file manager

I installed astro file manager and find the app you downloaded then hit the app apk file and here its prompt to install..
Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

I think that might be because you don't have a .apk installer app on your device.

If you do have one then try opening that and installing the app from there.
If it does not works that means that the APP is broken, requires a newer version of Android than the one you have on your device or it was designed to be used on a different type of device than what you have.

If you don't have an APK installer you will need to install one from the Google Play Store.
Alternatively you can also use adb (Android Debug Bridge) to install apps, but that requires a computer.

Comment: The APK installer is built into Android core – so it's very unlikely that it's missing. Much more likely that it's no APK file, or a broken one.

Comment: How do I find if my mobile has APK installer ? Just not to miss any option.

Comment: It is just a regural app, it should be at the same place where your other apps are. In my case it is located in a folder with other utilities such as Lamp, Voice Recorder, etc. (but my phone is not Samsung so it maybe somewhere else on yours). If it is not there try looking at the settings. It is very unlikely that you don't have one on your phone.

Comment: @learner1 From the phone's Settings, check for an entry called `Apps` (or a similar one), then allow showing system apps. The `Package Installer` is what you're looking for.